# Heston with Forward Dynamics

Tags: option-pricing, heston

I'm just curious if it's possible to use forward dynamics and work out the pricing formulas. Does anyone know if there's a reference (paper/url) I can look at?

Comment: Is your question how to price European vanilla options on a forward when it follows a Heston process?

Comment: yes. I'm asking whether it's possible to switch from spot dynamics to forward dynamics similar to black-scholes <=>black formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define a process $X$ to start at $X_0 = 0$ have the Heston-like $\mathbb{Q}$-dynamics

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathrm{d}X_t & = & -\frac{1}{2} V_t \mathrm{d}t + \sqrt{V_t} \mathrm{d}W_t^{(1)},\\
\mathrm{d}V_t & = & \kappa \left( \theta - V_t \right) \mathrm{d}t + \xi \sqrt{V_t} \mathrm{d}W_t^{(2)}.
\end{eqnarray}

with $\mathrm{d} \langle W^{(1)}, W^{(2)} \rangle_t = \rho \mathrm{d}t$ and such that $e^{X_t}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-martingale. The characteristic function of $X_t$ under $\mathbb{Q}$ is given by

\begin{equation}
\phi_{X_t}(\omega) = \exp \left\{ C(\omega, t) + D(\omega, t) V_0 \right\},
\end{equation}

where

\begin{eqnarray}
C(\omega, t) & = & \frac{\kappa \theta}{\xi^2} \left[ \left( \kappa - \rho \xi \mathrm{i} \omega - d(\omega) \right) t - 2 \ln \left( \frac{1 - c(\omega) e^{-d(\omega) t}}{1 - c(\omega)} \right) \right],\\
D(\omega, t) & = & \frac{\kappa - \rho \xi \mathrm{i} \omega - d(\omega)}{\xi^2} \left( \frac{1 - e^{-d(\omega) t}}{1 - c(\omega) e^{-d(\omega) t}} \right),\\
c(\omega) & = & \frac{\kappa - \rho \xi \mathrm{i} \omega - d(\omega)}{\kappa - \rho \xi \mathrm{i} \omega + d(\omega)},\\
d(\omega) & = & \sqrt{(\rho\xi \mathrm{i} \omega - \kappa)^2 + \xi^2 \left( \mathrm{i} \omega + \omega^2 \right)}.
\end{eqnarray}

This representation of the characteristic function is based on the numerically stable version provided in Albrecher et al. (2007).

Using $X$ you can now construct the underlying assets of interest and immediately obtain the relevant characteristic function. In case of a stock with dividend yield $q$, you set

\begin{equation}
S_t = S_0 e^{X_t + (r - q) t} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \phi_{\ln \left( S_t \right)}(\omega) = \phi_{X_t}(\omega) e^{\mathrm{i} \omega \left( \ln \left( S_0 \right) + (r - q) t \right)}.
\end{equation}

For a forward, you get

\begin{equation}
F_t = F_0 e^{X_t} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \phi_{\ln \left( F_t \right)}(\omega) = \phi_{X_t}(\omega) e^{\mathrm{i} \omega \ln \left( F_0 \right)}
\end{equation}

You can then directly employ your favourite characteristic function-based European vanilla option pricer - e.g. Fang and Oosterlee (2008).

**References**

Albrecher, Hansjoerg, Philipp Mayer, Wim Shoutens and Jurgen Tistaert (2007) "The Little Heston Trap," *Wilmott Magazine*, Mar.

Fang, Fang and Cornelis W. Oosterlee (2008) "A Novel Pricing Method for European Options Based on Fourier-Cosine Series Expansions," *Siam Journal of Scientific Computing*, Vol. 31, No. 2, pp. 826-848